# Error message when using Dplyr to filter with more than 3 levels to a factor

Tags: r

I'm trying to filter some factors in Dplyer, but instead of manually writing out the ones I wanted like c("Blue","Green","White") etc, I figured something like

`levels(df$factor.variable)[1:3]`

might prove faster, but if try to select more than 2 variables using the following code then I get the error message
**"longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"** and a big chunk of the data doesn't come through. With my dummy data below, 2/3 of the data disappears.

```
a <- 1:20
b <- rep(c("Blue", "Green", "White", "Grey"),5)
df <- data.frame(Numbers=a, colours=b)
df %>% 
  select(Numbers, colours) %>% 
  filter(colours==levels(df$colours)[1:3])
```

Note that if you only select 1 or 2 of the levels above (as in [1] or [1:2], not [1:3]), then the problem doesn't occur. Also if I remove one of the colours (factors) then I don't have the problem anymore.

```
a <- 1:15
b <- rep(c("Blue", "Green", "White"),5)
df <- data.frame(Numbers=a, colours=b)
df %>% 
  select(Numbers, colours) %>% 
  filter(colours==levels(df$colours)[1:3])
```

What objects have longer/shorter lengths? And why does 2/3 of the data disappear?

Comment: Use `%in%`, not `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were making mistake in dplyr. Instead of == use %in% solved the error.

```
a <- 1:20
b <- rep(c("Blue", "Green", "White", "Grey"),5)
df <- data.frame(Numbers=a, colours=b)
str(df)

df2<- df %>% 
  select(Numbers, colours) %>% 
  filter(colours %in% levels(df$colours)[1:3])
```

Comment: Ahhh, probably serves me right for not learning about Dplyr properly yet. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not a `dplyr` issue.

As others mentioned, `a == b` checks whether each pair of elements is identical, i.e. `a[1] == b[1]`, `a[2] == b[2]`, and so on. (Take a look at `?Comparison`.) You're comparing vectors of unequal lengths and with lengths that don't lend themselves to recycling one to fit the other, which is the reason for the warning you got.

Instead, `a %in% b` checks whether each element in `a` exists somewhere in `b`, and returns true or false for each element in `a`.

To illustrate with your data:

```r
library(dplyr)

a <- 1:20
b <- rep(c("Blue", "Green", "White", "Grey"),5)
df <- data.frame(Numbers=a, colours=b)
```

In the `a %in% b` representation, this is your `b`:

```r
levels(df$colours)[1:3]
#> [1] "Blue"  "Green" "Grey"
```

Checking for each element of `colours` being in that set of values yields a logical vector:

```r
df$colours %in% levels(df$colours)[1:3]
#>  [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [12]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

The base R version of `dplyr::filter` is like this, taking the elements of `df$colours` for which the previous operation yields `TRUE`:

```r
df$colours[df$colours %in% levels(df$colours)[1:3]]
#>  [1] Blue  Green Grey  Blue  Green Grey  Blue  Green Grey  Blue  Green
#> [12] Grey  Blue  Green Grey 
#> Levels: Blue Green Grey White
```

In `dplyr`, non-standard evaluation drops the need for `df$`, but you're doing essentially the same thing within `dplyr::filter`: finding whether each element of `colours` is in the subset of values `levels(colours)[1:3]`, and then filtering for only those rows corresponding to a `TRUE`.

```r
df %>%
  filter(colours %in% levels(colours)[1:3])
#>    Numbers colours
#> 1        1    Blue
#> 2        2   Green
#> 3        4    Grey
#> 4        5    Blue
#> 5        6   Green
#> 6        8    Grey
#> 7        9    Blue
#> 8       10   Green
#> 9       12    Grey
#> 10      13    Blue
#> 11      14   Green
#> 12      16    Grey
#> 13      17    Blue
#> 14      18   Green
#> 15      20    Grey
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, I don't think I really understood == all this time, thanks so much! I do wonder though, I've seen == used quite a lot with filter(). Should I just stick to %in% for multiple levels, and == for a single level? say:

filter(colour=="Blue")

Just trying to figure out when they're appropriate.